# Divide a string into binary indexes

Tags: ruby, split, divide

`a = '123712638126378123681273'`

i have

=> `a = ['12','37', ...... ]`

I tried to use split but I do not know how to order it

help me

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "binary indexes", but based on your example output, you might be looking for `a.scan(/../)`

Comment: Aside from the mysterious expression _binary indexes_, what do you mean by _order it_? For sorting arrays, you have the `sort` method. Please be a bit more precise when asking questions.

Comment: You might want to show the complete expected output (not just the first 2 elements). If it is too long to type, use a shorter example input. Also, include your code ("I tried to use split"), even if it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
a.scan(/\d{2}/)
#=> ["12", "37", "12", "63", "81", "26", "37", "81", "23", "68", "12", "73"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
a = '123712638126378123681273'
```

Code

```
p a.gsub(/.{2}/).to_a
```

Or

```
p a.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

Output

```
["12", "37", "12", "63", "81", "26", "37", "81", "23", "68", "12", "73"]
```

Comment: Can you explain the `gsub`-`reject` one? What are you substituting (are you?) and why the need to reject empty elements?

Comment: @Stefan For some reason, when I execute this `a.gsub(/.{,2}/).to_a` it prints with empty space at the end. I don't know why, so I have included the reject. You could help me here as to why this code `a.gsub(/.{,2}/).to_a` includes the empty space.

Comment: `{,2}` is equivalent to `{0,2}`, i.e. it matches 0, 1, or 2 times. To only match two occurrences, use `{2}`. (and maybe prefer `scan` over `gsub` if you don't want to replace anything)

Comment: @Stefan Oh that's exactly the problem, Now I have updated the answer. And regarding the `gsub`, spickermann has already used `scan` and I wanted to show another way so used `gsub`.